# Conditionally delete from 2 tables using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables:
**NoteBhpSetup**
Columns: *note_bhp_setup_id*, *node_id*, *created_by*
(note_bhp_setup_id is FK to below table)

**NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition**
Columns: *note_bhp_setup_id*, *node_definition_id*

I need to implement below logic:

- For a given *node_definition_id*, delete all entries from **NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition**.
- **IF**, for the deleted records, **NoteBhpSetup** has no associated rows left in **NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition**, then delete those rows from **NoteBhpSetup**

Here is the logic I have implemented:

```
@Override
public void removeBhpSetupForNote(String noteDefinitionId) {

    Query select = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT note_bhp_setup_id FROM NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition WHERE note_definition_id = :noteDefinitionId");
    select.setParameter("noteDefinitionId", noteDefinitionId);
    List<Long> noteBhpSetupIds =  select.getResultList();


    SQLQuery delete= NativeQueryUtil.getSQLQueryWithTableName(
            "DELETE FROM NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition WHERE note_definition_id = :noteDefinitionId",
            getEntityManager(),"NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition");
    delete.setParameter("noteDefinitionId", noteDefinitionId);
    delete.executeUpdate();
    this.flush();

    deleteNoteBhpSetupWithNoNoteDefinitions(noteBhpSetupIds);
}

private void deleteNoteBhpSetupWithNoNoteDefinitions(List<Long> noteBhpSetupIds) {
    SQLQuery delete = NativeQueryUtil.getSQLQueryWithTableName(
            "DELETE noteBhp FROM NoteBhpSetup noteBhp WHERE noteBhp.note_bhp_setup_id IN (:noteBhpSetupIds) AND (SELECT COUNT(ndef.note_bhp_setup_id) " +
                    "            FROM   NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition ndef " +
                    "            WHERE  noteBhp.note_bhp_setup_id = ndef.note_bhp_setup_id) = 0",
            getEntityManager(),"NoteBhpSetup");
    delete.setParameter("noteBhpSetupIds", noteBhpSetupIds);
    delete.executeUpdate();
    this.flush();
}
```

and below is how my Entity looks like :

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@AttributeOverride(name = AbstractGeneratedNumericIdEntity.ID_NAME, column = @Column(name = NoteBhpSetup.NOTE_BHP_SETUP_ID))
@Cache(region = CacheRegion.Names.TRU_CARE_ENTITY_CACHE_REGION, usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class NoteBhpSetup extends AbstractGeneratedNumericIdEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String BHP_NODE = "bhpNode";
    public static final String NOTE_BHP_SETUP_ID = "note_bhp_setup_id";
    public static final String IS_SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME = "is_system";
    public static final String NOTE_BHP_SETUP_NOTE_DEFINITION = "NoteBhpSetup_NoteDefinition";

    @Column(name = IS_SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false)
    private boolean isSystem = false;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = BhpNode.BHP_NODE_ID_COLUMN, nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private BhpNode bhpNode;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable( name = NOTE_BHP_SETUP_NOTE_DEFINITION,
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = NoteBhpSetup.NOTE_BHP_SETUP_ID, nullable = false ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = NoteDefinition.NOTEDEF_ID_COLUMN, nullable = false )
    )
    private Set<NoteDefinition> noteDefinitions = new HashSet<>();

    protected NoteBhpSetup() {}

    public NoteBhpSetup(final BhpNode bhpNode) {
        this.bhpNode = bhpNode;
    }

    public boolean getIsSystem() {
        return isSystem;
    }

    public void setIsSystem(final boolean isSystem) {
        this.isSystem = isSystem;
    }

    public BhpNode getBhpNode() {
        return bhpNode;
    }

    public void setBhpNode(final BhpNode bhpNode) {
        this.bhpNode = bhpNode;
    }

    public Set<NoteDefinition> getNoteDefinitions() {
        return noteDefinitions;
    }

    public void setNoteDefinitions(Set<NoteDefinition> noteDefinitions) {
        this.noteDefinitions = noteDefinitions;
    }


    /**
     * Use bhpNode and note definitions to generate hashCode
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getIdLazy(bhpNode), noteDefinitions);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings(value = "BC_EQUALS_METHOD_SHOULD_WORK_FOR_ALL_OBJECTS", justification = "if obj is not an instance of AbstractGeneratedNumericIDEntity the Hibernate.getClass(this) if statement is true and this method returns false")
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        // Check the state of the object
        boolean isEqual;
        if (this == obj) {
            // The object reference is the same
            isEqual = true;
        } else if ((obj == null) || !Hibernate.getClass(this).equals(Hibernate.getClass(obj))) {
            // The object does not have the concrete class as its base
            isEqual = false;
        } else {
            NoteBhpSetup other = (NoteBhpSetup) obj;
            isEqual =  getIdLazy(bhpNode).equals(getIdLazy(other.getBhpNode())) && noteDefinitions.equals(other.getNoteDefinitions());
        }

        // Return the equality status
        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

I feel like this is not the best way to do it, as I am hitting the database 3 times. Please can someone point me to a better way of implementing this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best solution but you can do something like this. You can first check if you need to delete data from one table or both.

```
SELECT t1.note_bhp_setup_id, COUNT(t1.note_bhp_setup_id) FROM notebhpsetup_notedefinition t1 
INNER JOIN notebhpsetup_notedefinition t2
ON t1.note_bhp_setup_id = t2.note_bhp_setup_id AND  t1.node_definition_id = ?
GROUP BY t1.note_bhp_setup_id
```

if `COUNT(t1.note_bhp_setup_id) > 1` for any of the returned row, you need to delete only from the **notebhpsetup_notedefinition** table. 
else delete all (`t1.note_bhp_setup_id`) rows from **notebhpsetup_notedefinition** and **note_bhp_setup_id** tables.